# nodejs equivalent Pattern.compile

Tags: javascript, node.js

this code on java/android work fine to find all texts between `<tag>` and `</tag>`

whats equivalent of my code on java on nodejs/javascript?

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<tag>(.+?)</tag>");

private void getTagValues(final String str) {
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // print found text
    }
}
```

for example:

```
var value = "<tag>text 1</tag> aaaaa <tag>text 2</tag>";
var regex = '<tag>(.+?)</tag>';
var match = regex.test(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (match) {
        console.log(value + 'is not a number that has between 1,20 digits');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @robertklep i read that recently, but my problem is extract all text between tags

Comment: Can you show the exact JS code that you used? The code that you posted isn't valid.

Comment: @robertklep i can wrote only that buy documentation, I'm trying to print all texts between this regular `<tag>(.+?)</tag>` on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code try this.This code is working as your expectations.Hope this helps for you.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.get('/tag',function(request,response)
{
var value="<tag>text 1</tag>,aaaaa<tag>text 2</tag>.";
var regex="<tag>(.+?)</tag>.";
var result=value.match(/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g).map(function(val){
var first=val.replace(/<\/?tag>/g,'');
console.log(first);
});
var match=regex.match(/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g).map(function(valy){
var second=valy.replace(/<\/?tag>/g,'');
console.log(second);
});
response.send("data send");
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Server is listening on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

See output in a browser as `localhost:3000/tag` and see the text between tags in terminal.